# Detect if 3-phase 110VAC motor is running via 24VDC PLC input

Tags: current, sensor, plc

We have an industrial machine with 3-phase ~250W AC (~2.5A @ 110V) motors on it.  I want to *non-invasively* detect if the motors are running.  That detection signal needs to feed into the 24V input of a Koyo Click PLC.

After some Googling and part-searching, it seems like I could use a non-invasive current-sense transformer, but the output looks like it's AC with a scaled current.  I still have to convert an AC -> DC signal.

I've also looked at various relays, but their input current requirements are generally very low (< 50mA).

Am I on the right track here by using a current-sense transformer that drives a solid state relay with AC-driven coils?  Or is there some easy-to-grab part that I'm missing?  I'm looking for something that is in-line, chassis mount, or DIN rail basically (no custom soldered circuit please).  My background is in PC software development, so this mini-project has been giving me fits.

Comment: Do you mean if it's free running, once it is disconnected? What is the purpose of detection? Is the feedback from the contactor not enough?

Comment: Just measuring current says nothing about if a motor is spinning or not.  You need either a speed feedback element, or even just a simple pulse pickup on whatever the motors are moving.

Answer (score 0):

Such things exist. (It's very hard to come up with an original question these days.) For example, the Crouzet Current Monitoring Relay with SP-NO/NC Contacts, 24 → 240 V ac/dc.

[image]

*Figure 1. A current sensing relay. See [RS Online](https://ie.rs-online.com/web/p/monitoring-relays/0261959/).*

Specifications for this unit are:

```
Operating voltage:              24 V → 240 Vac / Vdc (-15% / +10%)
Measurement range:              2 → 20 A
continuous overload (°25@C):    100 A
Measured signal frequency:      40 → 70 Hz sinusoidal
Measurement cycle (max.):       30 msec / Measurement in true RMS
Threshold setting:              10 → 100% of the range
Response time:                  200 ms
Start delay:                    500 ms
Output:                         1 single changeover relay
```

The relay contact can be used to switch your PLC input.

A websearch for current monitoring relay will give you plenty of options.